# Delaying recursive HTTP get request inside a do while loop in Angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-services, angular-http

I am consuming an external API recursively while waiting for the completion of another API call. 
The http calls are made by using `import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'`

I am new to the framework and maybe there is something done wrong in the code but the work-flow is as below:

The first API call is made by this block

```
initializeCrawling(): void {         
this.callCrawlInitializingAPI()       // this method is calling the api
  .subscribe(
    restItems => {
      this.groupCrawlingRestResponse = restItems;
      console.log(this.groupCrawlingRestResponse);
      this.isCrawlActive = false;
    }
  )

this.fetchResults();    // while callCrawlInitializingAPi call executes, this block here must executed on paralel.
}
```

Now I am declaring a global

> boolean

variable that will became `false` when `this.callCrawlInitializingAPI()` execute finish.

Here is the code for the second API call that must be called recursively.

```
fetchResults(): void {
this.fetchDataApiCall()
  .subscribe(
    restItems => {
      this.groupCrawlingRestResponse = restItems;
      console.log(this.groupCrawlingRestResponse);
    }
  )

}



fetchDataApiCall() {
    do {
      this.http
        .get<any[]>(this.fetchResultsUrl, this.groupCrawlingResultRestResponse)
        .pipe(map(data => data));
      console.log("Delaying 3000");
    } while (this.isCrawlActive);
  }
```

The Goal here is to delay the do - while loop by lets say 1 second.

I Have try the following:
1 - imported {delay} from "rxjs/internal/operators" and use as above;

```
do {
  this.http
    .get<any[]>(this.fetchResultsUrl, this.groupCrawlingResultRestResponse)
    .pipe(map(data => data));
  console.log("Delaying 3000");
  delay(3000);
} while (this.isCrawlActive);
```

2- use setTimeout() function as above:

```
do {
 setTimeout(function(){
 this.http
 .get<any[]>(this.fetchResultsUrl, this.groupCrawlingResultRestResponse)
 .pipe(map(data => data));}, 1000)
 } while (this.isCrawlActive)
```

None of them are working and as far as I understand the do while loop is not delayed, and processes a lot of calls as do while continues.

First of all I want to know how to make it work and second if there is a better way on doing this with Angular since I am new to the framework.

Thank you

---

**UPDATE**

My question has a correct answer if anyone will search for this in the future.

The only thing that I had to change was this line of code 
`clearInterval(intervalHolder.id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all when you are subscribing to a function containing http event, the function must return the stream/http-call

```
fetchDataApiCall() {
  return this.http
    .get<any[]>(this.fetchResultsUrl, this.groupCrawlingResultRestResponse)
    .pipe(map(data => data));
  }
```

After that if you want to delay the response, you must put the delay operator in the pipe, like that.

```
fetchDataApiCall() {
  return this.http
    .get<any[]>(this.fetchResultsUrl, this.groupCrawlingResultRestResponse)
    .pipe(map(data => data),
          delay(3000));
  }
```

### UPDATE

As the comments before the update says there is some trouble with the clear interval, so here is 100% tested solution for the case. The in the first block of code there is the polling logic, pretty much as long the `isActive` property is true, each 500 ms new request will be called.

The second block of code is the service that simulates the requests.

```js
export class ChildOne {
  longReqData;
  shortReqData = [];

  active = true;

  constructor(private requester: RequesterService) {}

  loadData() {
    this.requester.startLongRequest().subscribe(res => {
      this.longReqData = res;
      console.log(res);
      this.active = false;
    });

    let interval = Observable.interval(500);

    let sub = interval.subscribe(() => {
      this.requester.startShortRequest().subscribe(res => {
        this.shortReqData.push(res);
        console.log(res);
      });
      if (this.active === false) {
        sub.unsubscribe();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```js
@Injectable()
export class RequesterService {
  private counter = 0;
  stop() {
    this.subject.next(false);
  }
  startShortRequest() {
    this.counter += 1;
    let data = {
      delay: 0,
      payload: {
        json: this.counter
      }
    };
    return this.mockRequest(data);
  }

  startLongRequest() {
    let data = {
      delay: 3000,
      payload: {
        json: "someJSON"
      }
    };
    return this.mockRequest(data);
  }
  mockRequest(data) {
    return Observable.of(data).pipe(delay(data.delay));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I understand that the logic on this is clear and correct. But, seems like clearInterval() is not accepted on angular6. Am I correct?

Comment: `clearInterval()` is still not working and what is worse is that `if(this.isCrawlActive)` never checks correctly because `this.isCrawlactive` is undefined for a reason even though i declared `isCrawlActive = true;`.... Any tip?